# SQLite.net: Query one single column

Tags: sqlite.net

I have a model of the following form:

```
public class LanguageText
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string de { get; set; }
    public string en { get; set; }
    public string ru { get; set; }
}
```

How can I query just one column by Id? I tried this:

```
SQL = "SELECT [de] from [LanguageText] WHERE [Id] = \"1\""
var p = App.Database.QueryAsync<LanguageText>(SQL).Result.First();
```

This will return one whole row of LanguageText in p, while I want the contents of the [de] row as string only.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: try var result = await App.Database.QueryAsync<string>(SQL);    
    return result.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Doesn't compile. Message: "'string' must be a non abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync<T>(string, parames object [])'

Comment: How about conn.ExecuteScalar<String>?

Comment: Better! But still not what I need. I tried: value = App.Database.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>(SQL).Result.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
Looks better, it returns - guess that - the *first character* of the column contents. Almost there! (Consider posting an answer, so I can accept and give you the credits!)

Comment: Gotcha! value = App.Database.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>(SQL).Result; seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out

```
App.Database.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>(SQL).Result
```

Comment: Sorry for being smart-a**ed but you shoud never use `.Result` to get a result from an async task. Ref: https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/